# Text Over SSH Buffering

Tags: ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard, ssh, terminal

I'm always SSHing to servers, sometimes it's over TOR, sometimes it's a server that's far away and the latency is really high. Is there a way to buffer my key strokes locally before they are sent to the machine on the other end?

I'm often using the default Ubuntu terminal and the OSX terminal.

Comment: I don't understand why buffering your input would help with latency at all? I'd think you'd want each keystroke to be transmitted immediately??

Comment: @The Phoenix: Local line editing ("buffering") would make it easier to type command lines. High latency causes a big delay between pressing the key and having the letters appear, which is terribly inconvenient: I would sometimes enter a long command, wait up to two seconds for everything to be displayed, notice a ton of typos, kill and retype the whole line... With local editing, the keypresses would be visible instantly.

Comment: Sending fewer packets means using less bandwidth. Over a sufficiently slow link, using less bandwidth means improved latency.

Comment: @grawity - I see, well I suppose I get ya. I think in order for this to work, your ssh client MUST implement some kind of support for this. I'd look to the ssh man page on OSX - but maybe you've done that and maybe they didn't bother to document everything.

Comment: I'm tempted to recommend typing in a text editor and then pasting into the terminal, but I would like a legitimate answer to your question myself.

Comment: @The Phoenix: It's mostly the job of the terminal, not the SSH client (unless they are combined, as is usually the case in Windows).

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry if buffer isn't the right word. Local line editing or readline editing would probably be better.

Comment: Similar question: [*How to enable “Local Line Editing” in openssh, like PuTTY?*](https://superuser.com/q/1530915/432690)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a better remote terminal experience over high latency and/or low throughput, I highly recommend you have a look at [mosh](https://mosh.org/).

Comment: This answer prompted me to try mosh, but it's not a drop-in replacement. So for others making the jump: adapt your existing ssh command to mosh by passing all of the ssh command except the `user@host` section into --ssh, so `mosh --ssh="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i path/to/key.pem" user@some-host`

Answer (score 0):

Old Telnet supported local line editing. I once ran telnet over SSH to try this feature but soon realized it being even worse - no cursor keys or ctrl-keys in editors or command-line.

CopyPaste is your friend or mounting directories.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* work, but your interactive experience will be broken in several ways (e.g., no TAB-completion, no ability to interrupt with `^C` on the remote host, etc.):

```
ssh -T remotehost /bin/bash --login -i
```

The `-T` option forces SSH not to allocate a pseudo-terminal, and it *may* cause the local `ssh` client to read a line at a time before transmitting.

Answer (score 0):

The command flag `-T` does work, although a found better user experience is to be found with PUTTY.  It has option for `"local line editing"` and `"local echo"`

The command string then only gets sent with 'Enter' key.

Comment: -T does not do "local line editing" or similar with OpenSSH (whihch comes with Ubuntu). -T is used to supress pseudo tty Allocation.

Comment: @davidgo He's not equating them.