# How to enable “Local Line Editing” in openssh, like PuTTY?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, putty, openssh

I used to use PuTTY to connect to servers from Windows. I found the settings "Local Line Editing" and "Local Echo" very useful. It prevents PuTTY from sending every letter I type to the server, otherwise it will become really hard to type complete commands when there is serious network delay.

[PuTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSBrL.png)

However, when I'm trying to use openssh to connect to a vps from linux, the problem starts to confuse me again. I want the line be sent to server only when I press Return.

Does openssh support local editing? How can I enable it? Or is there any other command line ssh tool that supports this function?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/302505/

Answer (score 1):

Run sole `cat`. The behavior of your tty is now kinda as you want: you can edit a line and `cat` will read it only upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This is because your shell configures your local terminal accordingly. When `cat` exits, the shell configures the terminal back to what the shell needs.

Interactive `ssh` (that allocates a tty on the remote side) is different. The shell still acts like with `cat`, but `ssh` *itself* configures the terminal to raw. See [this question+answer pair of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618) to get some insight why interactive `ssh` wants the local terminal to be raw.

A poor man's solution is to pipe `cat` to `ssh -tt …`. IMO this has too many downsides and it's way better to solve the problem without `cat`.

You want your local terminal to be somewhat [cooked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21760/108618) when using interactive `ssh`. For this you can use `stty` to change the settings of your local terminal. The problem is you need to do this after `ssh` configures the terminal to raw. If you do this before then `ssh` will simply override your settings. So you need to give `ssh` some time and run `stty` when `ssh` runs.

You may be tempted to do like `(sleep 10; stty …) & ssh …`. This won't work, [`stty` will get SIGTTOU and be stopped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600460/108618). A background process cannot reconfigure its own controlling terminal. The easiest way is to run `stty` in another terminal (i.e. under another controlling terminal) and tell it to target the first terminal.

Proceed like this:

1. In a terminal where you are going to run `ssh`, invoke `tty` and notice what device the terminal is. The output will be like `/dev/tty3` or `/dev/pts/3`.
2. Run `ssh` there. Wait until you are logged in.
3. In another terminal run `stty` with stdin redirected to the first terminal and with options that will give you "local line editing". Assuming the output from `tty` was `/dev/pts/3`, the basic command is:

   ```
   </dev/pts/3 stty icanon icrnl opost onlcr echo echoe echok
   ```

Notes:

1. The local line will be sent to the remote side only after you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. Any of the first three keystrokes will generate a terminating newline character that *will get* to the remote side. Even if you want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (to clear the screen) or e.g. sole `q` to exit a remote `less`, or <kbd>↑</kbd> to use the history of your remote shell, the only way to send it *without* a newline character is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. But…
2. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> twice (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> just after <kbd>Enter</kbd> or equivalent) then you will [cause the local `ssh` "see" EOF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701319/108618) it never expects while reading from a raw terminal (remember the tool has configured the terminal to raw and believes it's still raw). In my tests `ssh` stops reading after "seeing" EOF, it becomes virtually useless and has to be killed eventually (and the local terminal has to be reset with `stty sane`).

   You can disable the local function of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (and thus make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> generate `^D` that you can send to the remote side with <kbd>Enter</kbd>) by adding  `eof ''` to our `stty …` command, but then you will lose the ability to send something without a newline character at the end.
3. When you send a line to a remote shell, the shell will echo it on its own. This is normal. If you want to suppress this echo, you need to reconfigure the remote tty (`stty -echo`).
4. `opost` enables postprocessing output. We need this because we explicitly want `onlcr`, without it each remote echo will appear in somewhat unexpected place. There may be other postprocessing options affecting output and in general you may want to turn them off. If you suppress remote echo (see the previous point) then you don't need `onlcr` and you can disable local postprocessing of output (`-opost`).
5. Expect the local line editing to interfere with output of interactive remote tools that "take over" the entire screen (e.g. `htop`, `less`, `vi`, `tmux`). Such tools need to control the terminal. As remote tools, they can control the remote tty, not the local one. They know nothing about the local tty and thus the local tty should be as transparent as possible, so like a bi-directional fifo, i.e in the raw mode. In our case it's not in the raw mode and you will see the local line editing cause overwriting and scrolling, a mess in general. This by itself will not confuse the remote tool, it will confuse you though and possibly you will send some wrong input because of this.
6. **I'm not really sure the `stty …` command in this answer is *the* best one to enable "local line editing".** Read `man 1 stty`, experiment, adjust to your needs.